# Open Character Device without creating a Device Node

Tags: kernel, drivers

I'm having an issue where a 3rd party application is opening a device node it shouldn't.

I wrote a SPI Slave device driver that does some processing of messages. When the driver loads its in "Initialize Mode" which only replies to a specific message. To re-initialize communications I must unload and reload the driver. The problem is that the system has a 3rd party application, running as root, that opens all character devices. The only way to make this all work is to stop the app and unload which causes a huge problem with the over all project.

Is it possible to open a connection to a Character Device without actually having a device node? Right now I use fopen('/dev/spi') and everything works fine until I need to reload and the above issue ensues. Is there any sort of system call that can be made that would result in a file descriptor to a specific Major/Minor node number without having the actual /dev/spi file?

Comment: I don't think you can do it without a device node per se, but you can define *which*  and *where* based on maj:min or whatever with udev rules. It may also be possible to `mount --bind` over that `/dev` but I'm not sure if it would still be accessible to you after - probably that could be handled with mount namespaces though.

Comment: That application seems obnoxious. Can you run it chrooted?

Answer (score 2):

**If the offending application only opens device nodes in the `/dev` tree** then you could place your device node somewhere else, if that works with your own program.

The filesystem the device node lives on have to have the mount option `dev` set for it to have special treatment of device node files as such.

*(Disclaimer: I have not tested this, but I have done similar things before...)*

One example would be to mount a small `tmpfs` filesystem on, for example, `/my-dev/` and create the device node there.

```
mkdir -p /my-dev

mount -t tmpfs -o dev,size=<size> tmpfs /my-dev

mknod /my-dev/spi <type> <maj> <min>
```

where *`<size>`* is the size of the tmpfs, *`<type>`* is the device node type and *`<maj> <min>`* are the major:minor device numbers; see the man-pages for `mount` and `mknod` respectively.

...And then use `fopen("/my-dev/spi")` in your program.

(And, of course, make sure that `udev` or similar does *not* make a node for the device.)

Comment: I've tried moving it to different places in my root directory with no change. I'll have to try mounting a new fs like you suggested.

Comment: @jecxjo Do you know the mechanism the offending program uses for enumerating the devices? Does it just check everything in `/dev` or does it use some hook in `udev` or somewhere else (in the kernel, perhaps) or does it have some other way?

Comment: no idea, its a proprietary app that uses a 485 interface to a radio. Think they put in code to "auto detect" character devices. Cant change this code, just have to live with it.